# Mount Azure Fileshare on Desktop?

Tags: azure, file-sharing

I followed the instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/) and successfully mounted a file share connecting 2 VMs.

I'm wondering if it's possible to mount Azure Fileshare to my desktop running linux using a similar method:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //username.file.core.windows.net/testing /media/share/ -o vers=3.0,username=username,password=password,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't yet. Atm only Windows 8, 10 and Window Server 2012 (R2) is supported. You can mount it in a Linux VM running in Azure tho.

> The Linux SMB client doesn’t yet support encryption, so mounting a
>   file share from Linux still requires that the client be in the same
>   Azure region as the file share. However, encryption support for Linux
>   is on the roadmap of Linux developers responsible for SMB
>   functionality. Linux distributions that support encryption in the
>   future will be able to mount an Azure File share from anywhere as
>   well.

More Info:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/#overview